# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars this error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

> My example is here  where am i doing wrong 
>   I want to add the elements in the array to a variable, but every time I try, I get the same error.
>   Waiting for your solution suggestions

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

img =cv2.imread("23A96F0E154BE344A4C.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
height = np.size(gray, 0)
width = np.size(gray, 1)
lw=int(width*0.05)
h=int(height*0.05)
rw =int(width-(width*0.05))
#lw = leftwidth rw=rightwitdh

leftcornerdown = gray[h:h+10, lw:lw+1]
leftcornerright =gray[h:h+1, lw:lw+10]
rightcornerdown = gray[h:h+10,rw-1:rw]
rightcornerleft = gray[h:h+1, rw-10:rw]
toplam = 0

for i in leftcornerright:
    toplam += i
for i in range(0, 10):
    toplam += int(leftcornerdown[i])
    toplam += int(leftcornerright[i])
    toplam += int(rightcornerdown[i])
    toplam += int(rightcornerleft[i])
print(toplam)
```

> Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `lw:lw+1` by `lw` in left cornerdown and do the same in the 4 lines after. This should fix your error.

```
leftcornerdown = gray[h:h+10, lw]
leftcornerright =gray[h, lw:lw+10]
rightcornerdown = gray[h:h+10,rw-1]
rightcornerleft = gray[h, rw-10:rw]
toplam = 0

for i in leftcornerright:
    toplam += i
for i in range(0, 10):
    toplam += int(leftcornerdown[i])
    toplam += int(leftcornerright[i])
    toplam += int(rightcornerdown[i])
    toplam += int(rightcornerleft[i])
print(toplam)
```

Comment: print the value of `leftcornerright[i]` and you will see it is not at all what you expect and can be fixed by the indexing stuff I mention in my answer

Comment: I solved tihs problem when i try  Transposing 1D array to 2D column matrix using reshape

Answer (score 1):

let's print some thing

```
gray = np.arange(4000000).reshape((2000, 2000))
lw = int(width*0.05)
h = int(height*0.05)
rw = int(width-(width*0.05))

leftcornerdown = gray[h:h+10, lw:lw+1]
leftcornerright = gray[h:h+1, lw:lw+10]
rightcornerdown = gray[h:h+10,rw-1:rw]
rightcornerleft = gray[h:h+1, rw-10:rw]

print(leftcornerdown.shape)
print(leftcornerright.shape)
print(rightcornerdown.shape)
print(rightcornerleft.shape)
```

output:

```
(10, 1)
(1, 10)
(10, 1)
(1, 10)
```

here, `leftcornerright` and `rightcornerleft` are `(1, 10)` 2d array.

so you can't apply `int(leftcornerright[i])` since when `i=0`, `leftcornerright[i]` is a `(1, 10)` array, not a number or `(1,1)` array (scalar).

transpose your `leftcornerright` and `rightcornerleft` may resolve this.